# Unable to compare xls data from a cell with unicode string

Tags: django, python-2.7, xls

I am importing a .xls file and want to perform some checks on data written in specific cells.

I did this:

```py
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('foobar.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
if sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'special' or sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'Special':
    error_msg = 'The fourth column head should say "special"'
```

This throws error all the time even if the cell does say 'special'

I even did `print(sheet.cell_value(0, 3))` to double check. And `type(sheet.cell_value(0, 3))` shows its unicode, which is why im doing `u'special'`.

Why is the if statement always true? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'special' or sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'Special'
```

This line will always be true, as one of conditions is true.
'True or false' results in true.
Change 'or' to 'and' - in this case both conditions have to be true to full statement be true also.

```
if sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'special' and sheet.cell_value(0, 3) != u'Special'
```

This will work.